# Passing array to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can pass a list or array to ajax?

```
var intArray = [];

$.ajax({
    url: '/User/GetGroup',
    type: 'GET',
    data: intArray,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        $(result).each(function () {
            var id = this.Id;
            var nome = this.Nome;
            $("#Default").append($('<option></option>').val(id).html(nome));
        });
    }
});
```

Like this way, still doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean `intArray`, you would do it exactly the way you're doing it, but without a dataType, `result` is probably just a string.

Comment: Oh, and remove `traditional`, that could keep jQuery from "paramizing" the array properly.

Comment: it is a GET method, you shouldn't be doing this

Comment: are you using asp.net MVC? if yes then i have a solution

Comment: yes, I'm using an asp.net MVC, I'm calling a JsonResult.

Comment: And what doesn't work, do you get the data on the serverside? Is the ajax call failing? Does the success handler fire, are you getting any data, what is the data, should you parse the data, set a dataType, you have to be more specific?

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Comment: the signature of action is this: ActionResult GetGroup([System.Web.Http.FromUri] List<long> i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the array like that, or use `data: JSON.stringify(intArray)`.  In ASP.NET MVC, we use the JSON 2 javascript library, available in a Nuget package.

```
success: function (serverResult) {
    // create an object array from json string.
    var results = JSON.parse(serverResult);
    for ( var item in results){
       $("#Default").append($('<option></option>').val(item.Id).html(item.Nome));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used data: { i: intArray }, and works too!